# AsyncTask Android gerando NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, asynctask

Tenho essa classe estática em uma Activity onde sua função e realizar o download de um arquivo e salvá-lo no dispositivo do usuário. Testei em um dispositivo real na versão do Android 7.1.1 e 4.1.2 e funcionou corretamente. No entanto, ao lançar o aplicativo tenho recebido relatórios de erro de versões Android 7.1, 6.0 e 7.0 referente a NullPointerException do processo **doInBackground** na linha referente **catch (Exception e)**

Código da classe

```
private static class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private WeakReference<DownloadActivity> activityReference;

    DownloadFileFromURL(DownloadActivity context) {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        DownloadActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        activity.txt_status_progress.setText(String.format(activity.getString(R.string.txt_baixando_dados),String.valueOf(0)));
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {

        DownloadActivity activity = activityReference.get();

        int count;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            FileOutputStream output = activity.openFileOutput(FOLDER + File.pathSeparator + FILE_SQL, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txt_status_progress.setText(R.string.txt_erro_config);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        DownloadActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        activity.txt_status_progress.setText(String.format(activity.getString(R.string.txt_baixando_dados),progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        DownloadActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        new DownloadActivity.insertFromFile(activity).execute();
    }
}
```

O que pode estar causando esse erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente a activity, na qual o download ta ocorrendo, está sendo destruída pelo sistema mas a task continua rodando. E em qualquer lugar que você acessar a variável `activity`(ou qualquer variável que pertença à activity destruída) vai gerar um nullpointer, pois essa referencia não existe mais.

As AsyncTasks não seguem o mesmo ciclo de vida da Activity na qual a iniciou. Então é totalmente possível que a AsyncTask continue rodando enquanto a activity não existe mais. O que pode gerar o problema que você está tendo. Por mais que você tenha passado a referência da activity no construtor da AsyncTask, o Android pode ter a matado, logo a referência que você está segurando atualmente na AsyncTask é inválida e qualquer acesso de atributo ou método vai gerar nullpointer.

*Como você não deu informações de que seja possível mudar a orientação do celular para horizontal e se há a possibilidade de ir para uma próxima activity durante o download, vou assumir que ambas são verdadeiras.*

Tem algumas formas de testar essa hipótese.

1. A mais simples é apenas começar o download e fechar o app(matar o processo) e ver o que acontece.
2. Você também pode começar o download e trocar a orientação do celular pra horizontal, se possível.
3. Uma outra é ir nas configurações de desenvolvedor e setar a opção "não manter activities". Começar o download e ir abrir uma nova activity.

Provavelmente os cenários 1. e 2. vão de fato mostrar a causa do bug.

E uma possível solução seria você utilizar Fragments para, não apenas fazer o download, mas para qualquer utilização de Threads que acessam variáveis da classe.

Os Fragments tem um método chamado [setRetainInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182180/understanding-fragments-setretaininstanceboolean), que serve para manter a instancia atual do fragment quando ocorrer uma [configuration change](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes?hl=pt) na activity na qual o fragment está commitado.

Outra solução seria matar(chamar o método `cancel`) a AsyncTask no `onDestroy` da sua Activty.

Comment: Max Fratane, obrigado pela resposta. Você tem toda a razão, a orientação da Activity não estava configurada, no xml, para portrait para evitar a rotação da tela, mas eu já corrigi isso. Em relação a sair da Activity de downlaod, não há essa possibilidade, pois o usuário é direcionado a Activity de download e só após completado o processo é direcionado para outra Activity, isso é feito programaticamente. Vou realizar o teste 1 e 3 e implementar o método cancel no onDestroy como você sugeriu. Assim que terminar os testes eu marco a resposta. Obrigado mais uma vez!